# Failing to export large data from Kendo grid to Excel

Tags: c#, javascript, kendo-grid

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: wsURL,
                data: JSON.stringify(dataToExport),
                success: function() {
                    window.location = "../../handlers/GetData.ashx";
                    return false;
                },
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            });
```

Comment: It works fine when no. of records is less than 40000. When I was trying to troubleshoot in the Chrome dev tool, it seems to be failing in the above posted ajax call, I think it might have something to do with JSON.stringify.

Answer (score 0):

There are three basic methods of handling this depending on your current environment :

1>Setting the MaxJsonLength property default value within your web.config. (This will only apply to web-services that handle JSON)

2>Setting the MaxJsonLength property of a JavascriptSerializer object to perform your serialization.

3>If you are using MVC4 to handle returning your JSON values, you may want to override the default JsonResult() ActionResult and change the maximum size manually.

Comment: I am not using MVC4 and the MaxJsonLength is already set to its maximum value.